# How to Add Custom Policy in Network Policy Server (RADIUS) that will authenticate One Time Password

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008, radius

I need to implement a two way factor authentication on my Active Directory in Windows Server 2008.

To do this, I need to setup a RADIUS server which will handle that special authentication. So, in my windows server 2008 i have setup a Network Policy Server (NPS) which will serve as my RADIUS server. I follow the procedure on the following link: http://www.sysadmintutorials.com/tutorials/microsoft/windows-2008-r2/how-to-install-and-configure-network-policy-server-nps/

Now, my problem is that I don't know how will I define (or probably add a policy) in the NPS that a One-Time Password should be entered and validated to allow user to access the domain.

Is there anyway to implement this? Please help!! Thanks!!